# how can i use ^ expression properly in Flex?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I am trying to use the ^ expression to get any string that is not certain characters, but I can't seem to figure it out.
this is what I am trying to do
`STRING                      [^<>"<!!""!!>"\n]+`
but when I input one ! in the text it doesn't recognize it as string, is there a way to make this work?
just to be clear I want that any string would be a STRING with the exception of < > <!! !!> \n the problem is !!> I think.
thanks for the help!

Comment: `[…]` is a character class. It matches a single character, one of the set listed. Or, if you put a `^` at the beginning, it matches a single character which is not in the ones you list. Either way, it just matches one character. You can't use it to match (or not match) a multicharacter sequence.

Comment: @rici thanks! can you maybe help me figure out a way around this? cuz I cant seem to work around this, I need to be able to comment out text like so <!! text in the comment! !!> but than the ! is not identified in the text and I get an error, how can I fix this do you know?

Comment: There's an example [in the flex manual](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html#Start-Conditions) (about halfway down that page). It uses C comments, which use different symbols, but the principle is the same. I'd suggest trying to read the manual from the beginning, though. It will help you learn how to use the tool.